# proof that hamming code (7,4,3) is cyclic

Tags: coding-theory

On my notes of the lesson I have a proof that the dual code of the Hamming code (7,4,3) is not cyclic. But a code is cyclic if and only if its dual is cyclic and I have proved by testing each word of the code that the Hamming code (7,4,3) is cyclic (because each shifting of a word of the code is a word of the code). Can someone help me finding the mistake in this proof please?

---

I consider the generating matrix of the dual code: $$G^t=H=\pmatrix{0& 0& 1\\ 0 &1& 0\\ 0&1& 1\\ 1 &0& 0\\ 1 &0 &1\\ 1 &1& 0 \\1& 1& 1}$$
$v_1$, $v_2$, $v_3$ are the polynomials associated to the rows of $G$.
I consider $$R=\frac{F[x]}{(x^7-1)}$$
I observe that $v_1=x^3+x^4+x^5+x^6=x^3(1+x+x^2+x^3)$. So $1+x+x^2+x^3$ must be a multiple of $g(x)$.

$v_2=x+x^2+x^5+x^6=x(1+x+x^4+x^5)$. So $1+x+x^4+x^5$ must be a multiple of $g(x)$.`

I find $$MCD(g(x),1+x+x^2+x^3)=x-1$$

If there would be another generator of the dual it should divide $MCD(x^7-1,1+x+x^2+x^3)$, that means $g(x)\mid x-1$ and this is not true.

If I call $D$ the code associated to $x-1$, $\dim D = 6$, $\dim(D_{\rm dual})\ge 6$ and this is absurd because $\dim(D_{\rm dual})=3$.

I conclude that the Hamming code $(7,4,3)$ is not cyclic.

---

Thank you

Comment: I fixed the formatting, please check.

Comment: It's noit clear for me if $g(x)$ (in your proof) is the generator of the original code or the dual (same for $G$). Also, I don't understand why you write $G=H^t$. What we have is $G_d=H$  (generator of dual is parity check of original) - but both are $4\times 7$

Comment: You can get proper spacing by using `\mid` instead of `|`.

Comment: I corrected the text. $H$ is 7x3 and $G$ is 3x7, aren't they? Do you confirm that the Hamming code (7,4,3) is cyclic? Do you know another way to prove it?

Comment: $g(x)$ is the generator of the dual.

Comment: The $[7,4,3]$ Hamming code is not defined by a _unique_ parity-check matrix. Some choices result in a code that is cyclic, and some in codes that are not cyclic. **All** of these codes **are** Hamming codes: a set of $16$ binary vectors of length $7$ with the property that any two distinct vectors differ in at least $3$ places.  _Your_ choice results in a non-cyclic Hamming code, and so its dual is also noncyclic, as you have correctly concluded.  Please check your claim that the codewords of the Hamming code that you have generated from the _given_ $H$ are cyclic shifts of each other.

Comment: Thank you for your very useful answer. Actually I've just realized I made a mistake in my checking. Only one last question: could you show me an example of  a parity-check matrix for which the Hamming code (7,4,3) is cyclic?

Comment: The main point is that you need to use a different ordering of the bits to see the cyclicity. Try for example
$$
H=\pmatrix{1&0&0&1&0&1&1\cr0&1&0&1&1&1&0\cr0&0&1&0&1&1&1\cr}$$

Comment: It works!! Thanks, I got it!